# Find the remainder when $5^{119}$ is divided by $59$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

(The other similar post didn't help in this case)

I understand that $5^{119}\equiv 7(\mod59)$,
but how can I show that the answer is indeed $7$, and not for example $(7 - 59)$ or $(7 + 59)$?

Thank you.

Comment: All three of those answers would be sufficient, as $a\equiv b \pmod c$ implies that $a\equiv b+c\times n \pmod c$ for any integer $n$.  Sometimes people use modular notation to refer to the least positive remainder....if that's what you mean, then only $7$ is correct, since $7-59$ is negative and $7+59$ is greater than $7$.

Comment: It is not true that the answer "is indeed $7$". For this, you need to add more information (but not in the title, better in the post).

Comment: The remainder $\, r = a\bmod n\,$ is the (unique) natural  $\,r < n\,$ such that $\,r\equiv a\pmod{\!n},\,$ i.e. the least natural $\equiv a\pmod{\!n},$ see the linked dupes. Hence $\,r-n<0\,$ is too small (not natural), and $\,r+n\,$ is too large (not the least) to be the remainder.

Comment: The *calculation* of $5^{119}\bmod 59$ by FLT and mod order reduction is already done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1445181/242).

Answer (score 0):

Do you know Euler's theorem, or at least that for any integer $\;a\;$ and any prime $\;p\;$ we have that $\;a^p\equiv a \mod p\;$ ? If you do then it is easy ( the following is done modulo $\;59\;$):

$$119=59\cdot 2 +1\implies 5^{119}=5^{2\cdot 59+1}=\left(5^{59}\right)^2\cdot 5=5^2\cdot 5=125=59\cdot 2+7=7$$

Of course, any other answer equals $\;7+59k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ , so there are infinite answers to that problem.

Comment: What do you mean infinite answers? The reminder of something divided by 59 has to be somewhere between $0,1,\cdots,58$

Comment: @ArielFishbein I understand the problem given by the OP as a problem of equivalence classes mdulo $59$, that's all. It is **not** true that we *must* always work with the residues $\;0,1,2,...,58\pmod{59}\;$, though that's what is almost always used in this kind of problems. Any other full list of representatives will work just fine.

Comment: But you said that $5^{119}(mod 59)$ can be equal to more than one asnwer which is no true. How do you explain then

Comment: @ArielFishbein Of course it is true, as $$\;7\pmod{59}=66\pmod{59}=-52\pmod{59}=125\pmod{59}=\ldots$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: I meant that you said that $x$ has infinite sulotions if $5^{119}=x(mod 59)$